# IOS - Styling Section Headers in a static UITableViewController - IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to style a section header background / font style in a static UITableViewController?  I cant see any storyboard option to do this and as the table is static the table methods have been disabled in the.M file  - so I'm not sure how to apply styling programatically either?

Comment: Yes implement viewForHeaderInSection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UITableViewDelegate protocol defines a method viewForHeaderInSection which can be implemented in your delegate to return custom header views (works for static UITableViews as well). e.g:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // you can get the title you statically defined in the storyboard
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    // create and return a custom view
    UILabel *customLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 50.0f)];
    customLabel.text = sectionTitle;
    return customLabel;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // return a custom height here if necessary
    return 50.0f;
}
```